# OpenLayers - createBox() relative to map view rotation

Tags: openlayers

I would like to make ol.interaction.Draw.createBox() method to draw the box relatively to map view rotation. By default it is aligned with the coordinate system axes.

Current behavior:

[image]

Desired behavior:

[image]

I have tried making custom geometryfunction for ol.interaction.Draw to calculate the coordinates of the box with map view rotation taken into consideration but cannot get it to work.

It draws weird shapes like below:

[image]

My geometryfunction is as follow:

```
var geometryFunction = function(coordinates, geometry) {

    if (!geometry) {
    geometry = new ol.geom.Polygon(null);
    }

    var currentViewRotation = map.getView().getRotation();

    var firstCorner = coordinates[0];
    var thirdCorner = coordinates[1];

    var dy = thirdCorner[1] - firstCorner[1];

    var secondCornerX = firstCorner[0] - dy * Math.sin(currentViewRotation);
    var secondCornerY = firstCorner[1] + dy * Math.cos(currentViewRotation);
    var forthCornerX = thirdCorner[0] + dy * Math.sin(currentViewRotation);
    var forthCornerY = thirdCorner[1] - dy * Math.cos(currentViewRotation);

    var secondCorner = [secondCornerX, secondCornerY];
    var forthCorner = [forthCornerX, forthCornerY];
    var fifthCorner = coordinates[0];

    var newCoordinates = [];
    newCoordinates.push(firstCorner);
    newCoordinates.push(secondCorner);
    newCoordinates.push(thirdCorner);
    newCoordinates.push(forthCorner);
    newCoordinates.push(fifthCorner);
    geometry.setCoordinates([newCoordinates]);

    return geometry;
    
};
```

I have tried playing with the sin/cos and +/- in calculating the coordinates but nothing worked.

Does anyone have this figured out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those that may need that - below solution works (ol 4.6.5):

```
function geometryFunction(coordiantes, geometry) {

    if (!geometry) {
        geometry = new ol.geom.Polygon(null);
    }

    var firstCorner = coordiantes[0];
    var thirdCorner = coordiantes[1];

    var currentViewRotation = map.getView().getRotation();

    var secondCorner = [thirdCorner[0], firstCorner[1]];
    var forthCorner = [firstCorner[0], thirdCorner[1]];

    if (currentViewRotation != 0) {
        var verticesToRotate = new ol.geom.MultiPoint([secondCorner, forthCorner]);
        var anchor = ol.extent.getCenter(verticesToRotate.getExtent());
        verticesToRotate.rotate(2 * currentViewRotation, anchor);
        secondCorner = verticesToRotate.getCoordinates()[0];
        forthCorner = verticesToRotate.getCoordinates()[1];
    }

    var newCoordinates = [firstCorner, secondCorner, thirdCorner, forthCorner, firstCorner];
    geometry.setCoordinates([newCoordinates]);
    return geometry;

}
```

Then you have to add an interaction to your map:

```
alwaysHorizontalRecPolygon = new ol.interaction.Draw({ source: yourSource, type: "Circle", geometryFunction: geometryFunction});

map.addInteraction(alwaysHorizontalRecPolygon);
```

Answer (score 0):

ol for version 7.5.2 edit as

```
if (!geometry) {
        geometry = new Polygon([[]]);      
}
```

it work for me.